# Retrieve index in LinQ Lambda Join

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

I'm quite new to all the .Net stuff and just wondering about something I would like to do.
I've been using for some time the LinQ Lambda queries to return list values with the `Select` statement, like this:

```
        var data = list.Select((x, i) =>
            new
            {
                Index = i,       // <--- this is what I need!
                Value = x.Value,
                Text = x.Text
            })
            .ToList();
```

The thing is that I have a LinQ Lambda Join expression as it follows:

```
        var data = DataBase.Table1
            .Join(DataBase.Table2,
                x => x.Id,
                y => y.Id,
                (x, y) => new    // <--- I can't do the same here :(
                {
                    Index = ???, // <--- Here is where I need the index!!
                    Value = x.Id,
                    Text = y.Description,
                })
            .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
            .ToList();
```

My question is, **how can I retrieve the index in this second linq query as I did in the first?**

Comment: Are you sure Linq to SQL can translate `Select` with index to SQL? I think you first query will not work.

Comment: True, sorry, the first statements works with object lists. My confusion is beacuse the database tables I normally use are parsed to objects by EntityFramework. I've edited the question. The matter is that in the end all are IEnumerable lists so I think there must be a suitable way to do it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `Select<T>(Func<T,int,bool>)` with Linq to SQL. You will see NotSupportedException if you'll try to execute your first query:

> Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Select'

You can use this operator with Linq to Objects. Just move query execution to memory with `AsEnumerable()` call. With your second query add another projection after you received result of join and moved execution to memory:

```
 var data = DataBase.Table1
            .Join(DataBase.Table2,
                t1 => t1.Id,
                t2 => t2.Id,
                (t1, t2) => new { Value = t1.Id, Text = t2.Description }
            )
            .AsEnumerable() //otherwise next operator cannot be translated to SQL
            .Select((x,i) => new { x.Value, x.Text, Index = i})
            .OrderBy(x => x.Value)
            .ToList();
```

UPDATE: If you want index of t2, then you can use `GroupJoin` instead of `Join`:

```
 var data = DataBase.Table1
            .GroupJoin(DataBase.Table2,
                t1 => t1.Id,
                t2 => t2.Id,
                (t1, t2items) => new { Value = t1.Id, t2items }
            )
            .AsEnumerable() //otherwise next operator cannot be translated to SQL
            .SelectMany(x => x.t2items.Select((t2, i) => 
               new { x.Value, Text = t2.Description, Index = i}))
            .OrderBy(x => x.Value)
            .ToList();
```

If you need both indexes, then move whole join to memory:

```
 var data = DataBase.Table1.AsEnumerable().Select((t1,i) => new { t1, i })
            .Join(DataBase.Table2.AsEnumerable().Select((t2,i) => new { t2, i }),
                  x1 => x1.t1.Id,
                  x2 => x2.t2.Id,
                  (x1, x2) => new { 
                      Value = x1.t1.Id, 
                      Text = x2.t2.Description,
                      Index1 = x1.i,
                      Index2 = x2.i
                  })
            .OrderBy(x => x.Value)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: I'm afraid your answer is not what I'm looking for, I need the index inside the inner select of the join. I've edited my question.

Comment: Inner select of join returns single item. It does not have any index. Please clarify what index you want

Comment: It does return a list of items, the ones that match the conditions of the inner join, and if it returns a list, it has an index.

Comment: No. `Join` returns single pair of items - one from each collection. It does not return list of items. What index you want - index of `t1` from `Table1` or index of `t2` from `Table2`?